# JPA find grandparent entity given only child unique key

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I am using JPA & MySQL.

If I have a bunch of entities that are related as follows:

- Grandparent_entity has many Parent_entity (OneToMany). Persisted with a join table.
- Parent_entity has one Child_entity (OneToOne). Persisted with child_uuid in parent table.

If I am given only the child unique key, how do I get the grandparent entity?

My idea is a query with 3 joins - child to parent, parent to join table, join table to grandparent. Is this the best way?

Comment: JPQL or CriteriaQuery? Can you show your Entities how they are mapped to each other?

Comment: JPQL - i think i cracked it following this: https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-facts-multi-level-fetching/

Answer (score 0):

Using hql:

```
FROM grand_parent gp, parent p WHERE p.child.id = :id AND p in (gp.parents)
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
select g from Grandparent_entity g join fetch g.Parent_entity p join fetch p.Child_entity c WHERE (c.uniqueKey = :uniueKey)
```